# Can band-aids prevent or reduce acne scar formation?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, first-aid, acne, wound, bandaid-plaster-bandage

Can band-aids prevent or reduce acne scar formation?

It's known that keeping wounds covered is actually better for healing. Here are the reasons:
It keeps our skin cells from drying out so that scabs don't form.
Scabs can impede healing and increase scarring.
It protects the wound from re-injuries.

https://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/01/health/01real.html
https://www.scienceabc.com/eyeopeners/is-it-better-to-cover-a-wound-or-leave-it-exposed-to-air.html

Would the same apply if someone picks on their acne till there's bleeding, and use band-aids after washing their facial wounds properly? Can it actually minimize acne scars formation?

I haven't heard of dermatologists recommending band-aids for acne scar prevention yet. It can be quite difficult not to pick our skin with acne.